# Seeding Python's PRNG with a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, prng, random-seed

I notice that if I seed Python's PRNG with a tuple, I get different results each time I do it. That is, the Python 3.4 program:

```
import random
seed1 = ('Foo', 'Bar')
random.seed(seed1)
print(random.random())
```

prints a different number each time it is run. Is this because the seed taken is the `id` of the tuple `seed1` which is different each time?

What is the best way to use a tuple as a seed to the PRNG so that I get repeatable results? Is it simply `random.seed(str(seed1))`?

Comment: So you want the same result each time you call random as opposed to a random result?

Comment: @IanAuld, not exactly: I want the same output every time I run the above program; that is, I want Python to seed its Mersenne Twister with the same integer value generated from a given tuple.

Comment: Perhaps this will be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023660/how-to-generate-a-repeatable-random-number-sequence

Answer (score 2):

From a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580412/hashing-hiding-strings-in-python):

> For Python 3.3+, as @gnibbler pointed out, hash() is randomized between runs. It will work for a single run, but almost definitely won't work across runs of your program (pulling from the text file you mentioned).

So using python 2.x, running `hash('Foo', 'Bar')` will generally return the same result on the same computer each time which gives you the same initial seed. On python 3.3+ running `hash` against your tuple gives you a unique value each time.

If you want to have a consistent result with python 3.3+ look into `hashlib`. For example:

```
import hashlib
import random

seed1 = ('Foo', 'Bar')
text  = u''.join(seed1).encode('utf-8')
sha   = hashlib.sha1(text)
random.seed(sha.hexdigest())
print(sha.hexdigest())
print(random.random())

> python3 random2.py 
eb8fc41f9d9ae5855c4d801355075e4ccfb22808
0.738130097774164
> python3 random2.py 
eb8fc41f9d9ae5855c4d801355075e4ccfb22808
0.738130097774164

> python2 random2.py 
eb8fc41f9d9ae5855c4d801355075e4ccfb22808
0.628422839243
> python2 random2.py 
eb8fc41f9d9ae5855c4d801355075e4ccfb22808
0.628422839243
```

i.e. you'll have a consistent seed, but since the random modules differ in their implementation you still get a different random number.

Comment: Thanks: I don't mind if it isn't stable across Python 2 / Python 3.4, but there's something I don't understand: `random.seed(sha.hexdigest())` is sending a `str` to `random.seed`: how come the hash generated from this `str` isn't randomized in the way the docs describe for Python 3.3+?

Comment: @xnx I wish I had a better answer (this is a good question IMHO). A hint lies in the help of each function across versions. In python3 it states "For version 2 (the default), all of the bits are used if *a* is a str, bytes, or bytearray.  For version 1, the hash() of *a* is used instead."

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

If you do this:

```
def repeatable_random(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    while True:
        yield random.random()

for i, v in zip(range(20), repeatable_random(('Foo', 'Bar'))):
    print((i,v))
```

You get different values for the random series each time you run it.

If you do this:

```
def repeatable_random(seed):
    random.seed(repr(seed))      # Note 'repr' here
    while True:
        yield random.random()

for i, v in zip(range(20), repeatable_random(('Foo', 'Bar'))):
    print((i,v))
```

It is the same series 1=>n on different run of the Python interpreter.