# Hash collision with 2 strings in Python

Tags: hash, python-2.x

In the [MIT OpenCourseWare YouTube lecture on hashing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M_kIqhwbFo), the professor gives an example of two strings causing a hash collision in Python:

```
>>> hash('\0B')
64
>>> hash('\0\0C')
64
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: I edited the question to use the Python2.x tag rather than Python, since this is specific to Python 2. With the introduction of a `PYTHONHASHSEED` in Python 3.x, the hashes for both are not the same (and will vary run to run).

Comment: FWIW, here's the source:  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#l1262

Comment: python hash is not cryptographic purpose, use real crypto library.