# Map unique strings to integers in Python

Tags: python

I have a list, let say 
`L = ['apple','bat','apple','car','pet','bat']`.

I want to convert it into 
`Lnew = [ 1,2,1,3,4,2]`.

Every unique string is associated with a number.

I have a java solution using `hashmap`, but I don't know how to use `hashmap` in python.
Please help.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Dict in python works like hashmap

Comment: @RaminNietzsche, I can't speak for Java's hashmap, but Python's dicts don't give the integer indexes the questioners wants, especially alphabetically sorted (which was not specificially requested, but was evident in their desired output).

Comment: How do you work out the number to associate with a string?

Comment: @RaminNietzsche, still, you've got the right idea, you can use a dict to create a mapping this way: ``d = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(sorted(set(L)))}`` and then ``Lnew = [d[x] for x in L``.

Comment: Just a meta comment, it's fun watching the comments and answers pile up from users of various skill levels (of which I'm definitely not at the top of the stack) on these sorts of questions second by second, knowing it's got to be a duplicate question. StackOverflow is now so rich in such questions, it's the more complex questions that are its main concern now, so it's like everyone (myself included) is excited to find one they can answer competently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a quick solution:

```
l = ['apple','bat','apple','car','pet','bat']
```

Create a dict that maps all unique strings to integers:

```
d = dict([(y,x+1) for x,y in enumerate(sorted(set(l)))])
```

Map each string in the original list to its respective integer:

```
print [d[x] for x in l]
# [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: I would just add ``enumerate(set(sorted(l)))`` since questioner didn't specify an alphabetical sort, but their desired output has it.

Comment: Also, you could use a dict comprehension: ``d = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(sorted(set(l)))}``

Comment: Whether this works depends on whether the OP wants just "a number" as described or in fact the first index+1 as shown in their output; also use a `dict` comprehension

Comment: `[3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]` is not the result OP wanted, am I missing something here?

Comment: The answerer didn't sort the list or 1-index the mapping. The following will use the same approach and give the same output: ``d = {k: v+1 for v, k in enumerate(sorted(set(L)))}``, then ``Lnew = [d[x] for x in L]``.

Comment: No sorting is not required.

Comment: I think you should remove sorting from your answer. You've basically added a GPS to a skateboard. It's much more expensive with little added benefit to the user. The cost of running this is O(N*log(N)), but originally was O(N).

Answer (score 4):

```
x = list(set(L))
dic = dict(zip(x, list(range(1,len(x)+1))))

>>> [dic[v] for v in L]
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: And, of course, use `x.index(v)+1` if you want the first word to have the number 1

Comment: Code only, *not* the desired output, and `list.index` is O(n) per call

Comment: Has quadratic runtime unfortunately, this can be done in O(n).

Comment: ``list(set(sorted(L)))`` and ``[x.index(v)+1...`` to get output questioner wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a map dictionary:

```
d = {'apple':1, 'bat':2, 'car':3, 'pet':4}
L = ['apple','bat','apple','car','pet','bat']
[d[x] for x in L] # [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2]
```

For auto creating map dictionary you can use `defaultdict(int)` with a counter.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
co = 1
for x in L:
    if not d[x]:
        d[x] = co
        co+=1
d # defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'pet': 4, 'bat': 2, 'apple': 1, 'car': 3})
```

Or as @Stuart mentioned you can use `d = dict(zip(set(L), range(len(L))))` for creating dictionary

Comment: I have a lot of strings. So copying manually in the code is not feasible.

Comment: @Mustafa I edited answer that how you should automate the dictionary creation

Comment: You could make the map automatically with `d = dict(zip(set(L), range(len(L))))`

Comment: @Mustafa You need to define the mapping between strings and integers somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a hashmap in Python, too, but we call it a `dict`.

```
>>> L = ['apple','bat','apple','car','pet','bat']
>>> idx = 1
>>> seen_first = {}
>>>
>>> for word in L:
...     if word not in seen_first:
...         seen_first[word] = idx
...         idx += 1
... 
>>> [seen_first[word] for word in L]
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: +1 for the most obvious and sensible answer; but how about `{x:len(L)-i for i,x in enumerate(L[::-1])}` to build the dict

Comment: @Chris_Rands I just realized OP does not want to go by index + 1, but give the first unique word the number 1, the second unique word the number 2, and so on. (I edited my answer accordingly.)

Comment: I now think what they actually want (based on the top answer) is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350029/assign-a-number-to-each-unique-value-in-a-list but frankly the question is not clear and should be closed IMO

Comment: @Chris_Rands yeah I'm confused now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> L = ['apple','bat','apple','car','pet','bat']
>>> l_dict = dict(zip(set(L), range(len(L))))
>>> print l_dict
{'pet': 0, 'car': 1, 'bat': 2, 'apple': 3}
>>> [l_dict[x] for x in L]
[3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Lnew = []
for s in L:
    Lnew.append(hash(s))  # hash(x) returns a unique int based on string
```

Comment: From the question, I think they're looking for 1-based integers, not the very long integers ``hash()`` gives.

Comment: consider providing an explanation to your code

Comment: `hash` does *not* return a unique `int` for each string. Hash collisions [are possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37127946/1959808).

Comment: The general approach here is fine if you explain that this is lossy encoding (mapping is not guaranteed to be 1:1 and may not be fully reversible). The bigger issue is that the built in hash function is not consistent for any two runs. hashlib with blake2s and reducing to int would be better.