# How to associate labels to data in matplotlib color bar and scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have currently 2d data `X` and a 1d vector `y` of color codes per row in `X`. I am trying to use the function `scatter` in `matplotlib` to assign a color code point in `y` to each row value in `X` with the following code using a label:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
classes = 2
zones = (['FEF', 'IT'])

X = np.array([[-1.61160406,  0.06705226],
       [-2.34304523,  0.19353161],
       [-4.39162911, -0.15401544],
       [-1.9107751 ,  0.67541723],
       [-1.76792646,  0.71884401]])

y= np.array(['c', 'mediumpurple', 'mediumpurple', 'c', 'c'], dtype='<U12')


plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], color=y)
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(classes)).set_ticklabels(zones)
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable

Comment: Your question in its current form is a bit confusing. It's always good to provide a small sample input for readers to understand the problem better. Even if you explain your problem by a 3x4 matrix or some small vector, it's helpful. I am unable to understand what does `per sample in X` means. What is a sample? A row, a column, a what? Why are you only plotting the first column `X[:, 0]` versus the second column `X[:, 1]`? What happens to the remaining `n-2` columns? I am sorry but you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show, don't tell

Comment: @Keatinge: What do you mean?

Comment: @bazingaa thanks for the feedback updated with clarification.

Comment: @Bazingaa I mean instead of using words to tell us about the arrays and vectors, he should just show them in the code

Comment: @user3025898: Can you put in your question first 5 values of `X[:, 0]`, `X[:, 1]`, and `y`?

Comment: @user3025898: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: updated with 5 first values of the arrays

Comment: Ok, thanks. You code works fine for me on `python 3.6.5` and `matplotlib 2.2.2`. What version are you using?

Comment: thanks for the comment @Bazzingaa now updated with error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was not in the `plt.scatter` but in the `plt.colorbar`. This was not clear from the initial question because you didn't include the second command before. It took some comments to find the problem.

The problem was that you were not creating any color map but was trying to show it without having any mappable numerical values to your color map. The solution below does the following things:

- First find the unique colors in your color array using `np.unique`.
- Then, create a custom color map using `ListedColormap` from your defined colors. This was inspired by the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib). I upvoted it, so should you.
- Mapping the strings (colors) to integers. I found how to do this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203215/map-unique-strings-to-integers-in-python). I upvoted it, so should you.
- Last but not the least, use the mapped values as colors with the custom created color map.

---

---

Here is a complete solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

classes = 2
zones = (['FEF', 'IT'])

X = np.array([[-1.61160406,  0.06705226],
       [-2.34304523,  0.19353161],
       [-4.39162911, -0.15401544],
       [-1.9107751 ,  0.67541723],
       [-1.76792646,  0.71884401]])


y = np.array(['c', 'mediumpurple', 'mediumpurple', 'c', 'c'], dtype='<U12')
cmap = ListedColormap(np.unique(y))
# print (np.unique(y))
# ['c' 'mediumpurple']

# Mapping the colors to numbers
dics = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(sorted(set(y)))}
y_mapped = [dics[x] for x in y]
# print (y_mapped)
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y_mapped, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(classes)).set_ticklabels(zones)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. I actually went from a vector of ints in y to color codes. The key discovery for me here was Listedcolormap. I assumed that color maps could only be used with the color maps provided by matplotlib such as jet.