# Hashing Password in .py file

Tags: python, hash, passwords, account

how i said in the title, i want the password to be hashed when is saved. Its possible with this?

```
    def __OnClickSaveLoginButton(self):
    id = self.idEditLine.GetText()
    pwd = self.pwdEditLine.GetText()
    if (len(id) == 0 or len(pwd) == 0):
        self.PopupNotifyMessage("ID and Password required",self.SetIDEditLineFocus)
        return
    file_object  = open("account.cfg", "w")
    file_object.write(id+"\n"+pwd)
    self.PopupNotifyMessage("Saved.",self.SetIDEditLineFocus)
    file_object.close()
```

Comment: Where is the hashing part?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Check out `hashlib`, pythons builtin hashing library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hashing (hiding) strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580412/hashing-hiding-strings-in-python)

Comment: @SuperStew i don`t have it. Im looking for a hash version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the python [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/hashlib.html). An example could look something like this:

```
  import hashlib

  def valid_password(userid, password):
      user = get_user(userid)
      pw_hash = hashlib.sha256(password).hexdigest()
      if user.hash == pw_hash:
          return True
      return False
```

Also I recommend reviewing some password storage best practices noted in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

Edit: I used sh256 in this example, but that is more useful as a message digest. A better use would be `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` or another key derivation function. There is a good write up [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Comment: But u could help me to fit my code in this hashing progress?

Comment: But i have one more question. When im trying to log in, the password remains "hashed". How to decode at login? I used just                              pw_hash = hashlib.sha256(password).hexdigest()

Comment: You won't be able to decode it. What you will need to do is rehash it and compare it to the hash that you stored to make sure they match.

Comment: As nudies mentioned at the end, DO NOT use a single round only, and DO NOT use a straight hash function.   Use bcrypt, scrypt, pbkdf2 or argon2.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to hash passwords in Python, as nudies mentioned, hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac is correct.

If you want to save the result in Base64, that's a reasonable option, as it turns it into a character string.

Just remember you also have to store the salt and the number of iterations; choose as high a number of iterations as your CPU can stand.

DO NOT request more bytes of output than the native hash function can support; for instance, PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 caps out at 64 bytes for password hashing; the others less.

I have a fully working example at [my github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Python-Builtin), including test vectors for all the normal SHA variants, of which the core piece is

```
import argparse,hashlib,base64,timeit
BinaryOutput = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',args.password, args.salt, args.iterations, args.outputBytes)
BinaryOutput.encode('base64')
```